# How to have a Date Input Keyboard for UITextField in Xcode / iOS

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield

**The problem:** For the UITextField, there are several selections of keyboard to use.  For inputting dates, certain number pads may be used, but they either appear to have too many keys there or too less.  The closest is the 'Phone Pad' or the 'Number Pad' -- but either is sufficient to have something like '/' or '-' as keys.

**The questions:** Is there a way to extend these built-in keyboards (e.g. the Number Pad) for just inputting dates?  The best solution would be that the 'Date Keyboard' can be added to the Xcode, but I'd settle to have one for my own code by adding it programmatically.

I guess the same goes for other types of input keyboards, such as temperature (with different units), weight, height, etc.

Any suggestions and sharing the code / experience would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this code:

```
 UIDatePicker *dp = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
 yourTextField.inputView = dp;
```

Do not forget to make an outlet for the text field and replace the `yourTextField` with your outlet name!

Comment: Cool.  Thanks.  Two more questions: 1). UIDatePicker is of different appearance than a keyboard. Is there a custom keyboard class / object that is similar to the Number Pad?  2). Is there a way to integrate this into Xcode's Storyboard / Canvas?

Comment: @user2734952 You welcome! Do not forget the check on the left.

Comment: @user2734952 1. You will have to subclass a UIView and create it yourself. 2. I do not think so